# Integrate Parse.com from Website

Tags: parse-platform

I have to prepare a web Admin for the mobile apps that have *iPhone and android versions*. I don't know how to send the push notifications to specific users or to all users from my **ASP.net web Admin**.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [rest API](https://parse.com/docs/rest#push). 
Pratically you have to perform a POST (using maybe RestSharp) passing your app id\key and the content of the push.